Color difference in photoshop from blender
My color is always different when I open a .tif or. Png in photoshop or Affinity Photo from what the render view looks like in Blender. Is there a consistent answer to this in color management for cycles renders? How do I get still images to look as they appear in render?

There is no consistent answer, because there is no consistent context. There can be many different circumstances so a single answer is not possible.

I mean for all possible situations. More context would be helpful. What monitor are you using? Can you share color management settings screenshot?

Wide gamut viewsonic monitor, windows, photoshop set to adobe98

Not sure what "photoshop set to adobe98 " means, but you have to make sure Blender's Display Device is set to color space your monitor actually displays(or is supposed to/setup to match). Then you need to make sure when you open the images in Photoshop you assign the right color profiles to them(assign, not convert) because Blender doesn't save any info about color space when saving images and they are likely to be assumed to be in sRGB. And then Photoshop must recognize display device correctly as well...

My advice would be to set the monitor up to display sRGB(if it has settings for that), then just leave everything on defaults and don't touch Photoshop's color management settings at all(reset to defaults). Unless you have a good reason to do something else. This way you will avoid whatever mess doesn't work right in the OS color management. If you work in anything else than sRGB, you have to know precisely what happens to colors at any step. If your monitor cannot display sRGB, I think you should provide more information about it and your use case.

Set View Transform in render settings to Standard:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Also when you add an Image Texture to your shader, make sure it's set to sRGB color space.

Sorry, I gave the answer a down-vote. How can you know they are using an sRGB monitor? This cannot be a general answer. What if they don't want a Standard color transform?.. What if they use P3 monitor, Blender set up as sRGB, then Photoshop converts to P3 for display? What if they use P3, Blender set up for P3, but since Blender does not attach ICC profiles, Photoshop assumes sRGB incorectly?..

@MartynasŽiemys No problem with the downvote, no hard feelings, but as for the argument: I don't know :D I routinely gave an answer that I'd bet 1 to 100 that it is the correct answer [in this case], but you might be right, it's not generalized.

It seems we are talking about some sort of wide gamut monitor without knowing its color space and what seems to be random settings in Photoshop's color management... This might be more complicated than it seems.

The View Transform > Standard cannot be the solution, because PNG is not like EXR saving linear data or something like that. When the view is transformed to e.g. Filmic, then the transformed colors will be saved as such in the PNG. I would rather assume like @MartynasŽiemys that is has something to do with display device settings and how Photoshop handles the file and what monitor is actually used.
